# Conver MySQL procedure in MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS amount_in_stock;
CREATE PROCEDURE amount_in_stock( @id INT)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SELECT drugs.name, SUM(arrivals.amount) AS Amount_arived, SUM(realization.amount) AS Amount_realized, SUM(arrivals.amount) - SUM(realization.amount) AS amount_in_stock
  FROM drugs
  JOIN arrivals ON drugs.id_drug = arrivals.id_drug
  JOIN realization ON drugs.id_drug = realization.id_drug
  WHERE drugs.id_drug = @id;
END; 
 GO
```

I convert mysql code to mssql but have an error

> column drugs.name not allowed

Please help me to fix this error.

Comment: That doesn't look like a MySQL procedure to me.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Group by drugs.name` after WHERE clause.

So your Procedure will be

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS amount_in_stock;
CREATE PROCEDURE amount_in_stock( @id INT)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SELECT drugs.name, SUM(arrivals.amount) AS Amount_arived, SUM(realization.amount) AS Amount_realized, SUM(arrivals.amount) - SUM(realization.amount) AS amount_in_stock
  FROM drugs
  JOIN arrivals ON drugs.id_drug = arrivals.id_drug
  JOIN realization ON drugs.id_drug = realization.id_drug
  WHERE drugs.id_drug = @id
  GROUP BY drugs.name
  ;
END; 
 GO
```

You can't use columns which are not in `GROUP BY` or Not in Aggregate functions and not are constants along with Aggregate functions like `SUM, AVG, MAX` etc.